# Display SwiftUI modal from UIKit view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

I have got a modal sheet built with `SwiftUI` but the rest of my app is `UIKit`. I want to display modal when user taps a button in `UIKit`. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do it like this

```
  let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: MyModalView()
self.present(hostingController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load your SwiftUI view using `UIHostingController(rootView: YourSwiftUIView())`
and present it in your `UIKit`

Comment: Can you show me how can I do the reverse ?
display UIKit view in swiftUI ?
When the swiftUI vie appear the UIkit view display as sheet style.